# Debugging COM objects using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, debugging, com, visual-studio-2022, com-interop

I try to debug a COM object using Visual Studio 2022 but can't get the internal values from it. Everything is in place, my object is already displayed as {System.__ComObject} but I like to visualize in a Watch window the data it contains.
There is also exactly the same question as this one, in this link:
[Enable native code debugging to deep into COM-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467025/enable-native-code-debugging-to-deep-into-com-object)
but unfortunately for Visual Studio 2022 that is not a solution and I do not have enough points reputation to add a comment, so my only choice is to create a new one.

Any idea is welcome!

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work in the accepted answer in the linked question, and show some code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Unfortunately In Visual Studio 2022 there is no option Tools-->Options-->Debugging -> enable the option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" as the solution in the link described.

Comment: That option used to enable an older version of the managed debugging engine.  The good one, last used in VS2010.  They rewrote the engine, unfortunately with a lot of bugs and missing functionality.  They did a lot of work in VS2017 and VS2019 to lower the bug bar, to the point that turning on that option wasn't necessary anymore.  Since it was fundamental 32-bit code, it couldn't be continued into VS2022.  Some COM objects just don't provide a peek at their properties at all, particularly so if it doesn't implement IDispatch.  You need to debug the COM library itself, source required.